# Issue from SQL query case statement to a linq extension methods in C#

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I need help with the following SQL query to write in linq or extension methods query if both can provide both examples would be great for me.

This query is returning the last id entered by the user and will return an material id which is what I need for my c# program will use it.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    CASE  
       WHEN s.Material = 'P4861VAPF' THEN 4578
       WHEN s.Material = 'P2871VAPF' THEN 4579
       WHEN s.Material = 'P2231VAPF' THEN 4580
       ELSE NULL 
    END AS MaterialSelected
FROM
    dbo.Shipments s
WHERE
    s.material <> ''
ORDER BY
    s.Id
```

I wrote this linq extension method in C# to re-create my SQL query is not working correctly is return the Id instead my select case statement

```
public int GetLastShipmentMaterialEntry()
{
    var lastShipmentMaterialEntry = BarcodeReceivingDbContext.Shipments
            .Where(s => s.Material != "")
            .OrderBy(s => s.Id)
            .Select(s =>
                s.Material == "P4861VAPF" ? 4578 :
                s.Material == "P2871VAPF" ? 4579 :
                s.Material == "P2231VAPF" ? 4580 : 0)                
            .FirstOrDefault();

    return lastShipmentMaterialEntry;
}
```

I have seen other query examples from other question here in stack overflow and google but not to exact of my current query. I also tried to use linqpad to see if there it could translate it but no luck so any help is appreciate it.

Comment: I would use TOP 1 and the order by s.Id instead of having to query the same again in the where clause.

Comment: Hello sean lange, the top 1 worked better thanks on that, but to translate my query to either extension method or linq you have an example?

Comment: I updated the query example to use the top 1 and order by id but again to write it extension method or linq

Comment: I updated my body description forgot to add my c# linq query extension I wrote to translate the sql query

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue and I was able to create linq extension method based on my SQL Query, thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to re-create my SQL query using the Linq extension methods, if anyone thinks and sees a a better solution please let me know.

```
        public int GetLastShipmentMaterialEntry()
        {
            var lastShipmentMaterialEntry = BarcodeReceivingDbContext.Shipments
                .Where(s => s.Material != "")
                .OrderByDescending(s => s.Id)
                .Select(s =>
                    s.Material == "P4861VAPF" ? 4578 :
                    s.Material == "P2871VAPF" ? 4579 :
                    s.Material == "P2231VAPF" ? 4580 : 0)               
                .FirstOrDefault();

            return lastShipmentMaterialEntry;
        }
```